# The object cannot move

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

The code has no error but mycar could not move. Do I define the for loop wrongly? I also tried to move the for loop to def moveit(self,vx,vy) but there is no difference.
Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import time
class Example(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)

        #create a canvas
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(width=600, height=250)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.road()
        self.crossing()

    def road(self):
        self.canvas.create_line(50, 50, 450, 50)
        self.canvas.create_line(50, 100, 450, 100)

    def crossing(self):
        self.canvas.create_line(350, 50, 350, 100)
        self.canvas.create_line(375, 50, 375, 100)


class Car:
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2, vx, vy, color, example):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y2 = y2
        self.vx = vx
        self.vy = vy
        self.color = color
        self.example = example

    def drawit(self, x1, y1, x2, y2, color):
        self.example.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill=color)

    def moveit(self, vx, vy):
        self.example.canvas.move(self, vx, vy)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    my_canvas = Example(root)
    my_canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    mycar = Car(60, 60, 125, 90, 20, 0, "red", my_canvas)
    mycar.drawit(60, 60, 125, 90, "red")
    mycar.moveit(20, 0)
    print(mycar.x1)
    root.update()
    root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: It looks like that will, at best, show the car at 40,60 and do nothing else (unless there are errors or other mistakes; I haven't tried running it).

Comment: My mistake; 80,60.

Comment: Which for loop? I don't see any for loop in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't see your car move because you do not give the right argument to the `move` function:

`self.example.canvas.move(self, vx, vy)` : here `self` is the `Car` object and it isn't the index/tag of the rectangle representing the car on the canvas. So that's normal that nothing happens. You should register the index of the car when you draw it on the canvas:

```
def drawit(self, x1, y1, x2, y2, color):
    self.index = self.example.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill=color)
```

And then move it with `self.example.canvas.move(self.index, vx, vy)`.

In addition, there is no point in taking again `x1`, `y1`, ... as arguments to `drawit`, since they are attributes of the car. You also forgot to increment the position of the car when it moves in `moveit` and I recommend you to use the `after` method instead of a for loop to create an animation. So I rewrote your code with my suggestions:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)

        #create a canvas
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(width=600, height=250)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.road()
        self.crossing()

    def road(self):
        self.canvas.create_line(50, 50, 450, 50)
        self.canvas.create_line(50, 100, 450, 100)

    def crossing(self):
        self.canvas.create_line(350, 50, 350, 100)
        self.canvas.create_line(375, 50, 375, 100)

class Car:
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2, vx, vy, color, example):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y2 = y2
        self.vx = vx
        self.vy = vy
        self.color = color
        self.example = example

    def drawit(self):
        self.index = self.example.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2, fill=self.color)

    def moveit(self):
        self.example.canvas.move(self.index, self.vx, self.vy)
        self.x1 += self.vx
        self.x2 += self.vx
        self.y1 += self.vy
        self.y2 += self.vy
        self.example.after(100, self.moveit)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    my_canvas = Example(root)
    my_canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    mycar = Car(60, 60, 125, 90, 20, 0, "red", my_canvas)
    mycar.drawit()
    mycar.moveit()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That works! Thankyou. What's the difference between this code?
`for i in range(0,200):
        mycar.moveit(20, 0)
        print(mycar.x1)
        time.sleep(0.005)`

Comment: Your GUI will be frozen during the sleep time (you cannot click a button ...), while it won't be with the after method.